# Como fornecer suporte a línguas estrangeiras nas aplicações android?

Tags: android, xml

Como internacionalizar uma `TextView` no Android, alguém poderia me dar um exemplo.

```
     <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView4"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:text="Resultado: "
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: Acho que o que você quis dizer foi: Como fornecer suporte a línguas estrangeiras nas aplicações android. Certo?

Comment: sim, por exemplo se um país de fora abaixar ficar o traduzido pela língua local ou para o inglês.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para dar suporte a línguas estrangeiras, você deve criar uma pasta **values-"cod"** - onde **"cod"** é um código de duas letras que identifica a língua para a qual você está dando suporte. Você pode consultar esta [tabela](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) para ver o código de outras línguas -dentro da pasta **res** e inserir dentro da pasta **values-"cod"** um arquivo **strings.xml** traduzido para a língua desejada.

**Ex.:** Se você quiser dar suporte, por exemplo, a espanhol e francês, você deve criar duas pastas **values-es** e **values-fr** dentro da pasta **res**, e deve criar dois arquivos **strings.xml** - cada um com a tradução para uma língua - nas pastas correspondentes:

```
res/
   values/
       strings.xml
   values-es/
       strings.xml
   values-fr/
       strings.xml
```

O arquivo **strings.xml** dentro da pasta **values-es** ficaria assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <string name="title">Mi Aplicación</string>
   <string name="hello_world">Hola Mundo!</string>
</resources>
```

E o arquivo **strings.xml** dentro da pasta **values-fr** ficaria assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="title">Mon Application</string>
  <string name="hello_world">Bonjour le monde !</string>
</resources>
```

Para mais informações:

- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources